# Multiple sticky headers in a React native scrollview

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I am trying to have multiple sticky headers in a React Native scrollview using `stickyHeaderIndices` prop but it only sticks the last header.

For example the following code with only stick `This is the title 2` when I would expect to have the three titles on the top of the screen.

```js
export default function App() {
  return (
    <ScrollView style={styles.container} stickyHeaderIndices={[0, 1, 2]}>
      <Text style={styles.title}>
        This is the title 0
      </Text>
      <Text style={styles.title}>
        This is the title 1
      </Text>
      <Text style={styles.title}>
        This is the title 2
      </Text>
      <AssetExample />
      <AssetExample />
      <AssetExample />
      <AssetExample />
      <AssetExample />
    </ScrollView>
  );
}
```

Here is a reproduction code: https://snack.expo.dev/@abumalick/scrollview-multiple-sticky-headers. You can check in android and iOS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After seeing this implementation: https://github.com/deepseapenguin/react-native-sticky-header-flatlist#result

I understand that the purpose of sticky headers indices is to display only one header at a time. When the user scrolls to a new sticky header, it replaces the previous one. It is not intended to display multiple headers at a time.